# How to differentiate between adjuncts and complements? Specifically when the sentence has two prepositional phrases

Tags: syntax, prepositions, adjuncts, complement

When a sentence has 2 prepositional phrases, how I can determine whether the second prepositional phrase is a complement of the first prepositional phrase or it's an adjunct to the whole sentence? Like the sentence "I designed a car for humanity with a separated brake system"

Comment: And like the sentence "i put the candel right in the middle of the pumpkin"

Comment: The accepted answer to that question is about the difference between **arguments** and adjuncts, and it essentially says that anything not an argument is an adjunct. That dismisses the original question by changing the terminology. I have my own habits in using the term _complement_, and I never use the term _adjunct_ because it's ill-defined, but apparently there are other conventions, which would be useful to have explained clearly. The topic comes up a lot, and the answers are rarely helpful, it seems to me.

Comment: @jlawler the objection is invalid: both questions refer to adjuncts, and if the accepted answer there answered a different question, by referring to arguments, well, it's a wrong answer.

Comment: If the accepted answer is a wrong answer, why refer anyone to it?